# Python: import a module but avoid executing it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-headers

I was making a scrawler and want to randomize the request headers.
things goes like that:
In `configs.py` I have headers defined:

```
import random
user_agents = ['1', '2', '3']

def get_random_user_agent():
    return random.choice(User_Agents)

headers = {'User-Agent': get_random_user_agent()}
```

In `main.py` I have test code like that:

```
from configs import headers
for i in range(5):
    print(headers['User-Agent'])
```

The result is always the same one.
I reckon that the variable 'headers' was initialized when importing.
What I want is a randomized user agent.
Is there any best practice for this? Thank you.

Comment: Well, problems solved. I defined another function to return headers in configs.py.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way that Python works. All code is parsed as soon as the file is accessed, any code no in a function is executed immediately. This is why you can have a python script like this:

```python
import random
print(random.randint(1,10))
```

and you can just executed that file with python to get the random number.

Just define you headers in a function:

```python
def get_headers():
    return {'User-Agent': get_random_user_agent()}
```